# Create a custom project type in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

There are numerous standard project types in Visual Studio (File->New->Project).

How do I create a **custom project type** and install it?

Comment: Did you google? http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2012/01/05/Creating-custom-project-and-file-template-with-wizard-for-Visual-Studio.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article on MSDN has the information you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx

Multi-project templates can be created using this tool to help: http://vsix.codeplex.com/